# Python - Find x and y values of a 2D gaussian given a value for the function

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian

I have a 2D gaussian function `f(x,y)`. I know the values `x₀` and `y₀` at which the peak `g₀` of the function occurs. But then I want to find `xₑ` and `yₑ` values at which `f(xₑ, yₑ) = g₀ / e¹`. I know there are multiple solutions to this, but at least one is sufficient.

So far I have

```py
def f(x, y, g0,x0,y0,sigma_x,sigma_y,offset):
    return offset + g0* np.exp(-(((x-x0)**(2)/(2*sigma_x**(2))) + ((y-y0)**(2)/(2*sigma_y**(2)))))
```

*All variables taken as parameters are known* as they were extracted from a curve fit.

I understand that taking the derivative in `x` and setting `f() = 0` and similarly in `y`, gives a solvable linear system for `(x,y)`, but this seems like overkill to manually implement, there must be some library or tool out there that can do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Not sure to understand the question. You know all the parameters (sigmas and g₀), and you just search for an example x,y such as f(x,y)=g₀/e? Or, on the contrary, you are searching for a way to avoid `curve_fit`?

Comment: Also, what is this offset? You didn't mentioned it at first. But then it makes the peak at x₀,y₀ = g₀+offset, not just g₀. If so, should `f(x,y)` be `(offset+g₀)/e` or `offset+g₀/e`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are an infinite number of possibilities (or possibly 1 trivial or none in special cases regarding the value of `g0`). A solution can be **computed analytically in constant time** using a direct method. No need for approximations or iterative methods to find roots of a given function. It is just pure maths.

Gaussian kernel have interesting *symmetries*. One of them is the invariance to the rotation when the peak is translated to `(0,0)`. Another on is that the 1D section of a 2D gaussian surface is a gaussian curve.

Lets ignore `offset` for a moment: it does not really change the problem (it is just a Z-axis translation) and add additional useless term for the resolution.

The geometric solution to is problem is an **ellipse** so the solution `(xe, ye)` follows the **conic expression** : `(xe-x0)² / a² + (ye-y0)² / b² = 1`. If `sigma_x = sigma_y`, then the solution is simpler : this is a circle with the expression `(xe-x0)² + (ye-y0)² = r`. Note that `a`, `b` and `r` are dependant of the searched value and the kernel parameters (eg. `sigma_x`). Changing `sigma_x` and `sigma_y` is like stretching the space, and so the solution similarly. Changing `x0` and `y0` is like translating the space and so the solution too.

In fact, we could solve the problem for the simpler case where `x0=0`, `y0=0`, `sigma_x=1` and `sigma_y=1`. Then we can apply a translation, followed by a linear transformation using a transformation matrix. A basic multiplication 4x4 matrix can do that. Solving the simpler case is much easier since there are are less parameter to consider. Actually, `g0` and `offset` can also be partially discarded of `f` since it is on both side of the expression and one just need to solve the linear equation `offset + g0 * h(xe,ye) = g0 / e` so `h(x,y) = 1 / e - offset / g0` where `h(xe, ye) = exp(-(xe² + ye²)/2)`. Assuming we forget the translation and linear transformation for a moment, the problem can be solve quite easily:

`h(xe, ye) = 1 / e - offset / g0` 
`exp(-(xe² + ye²)/2) = 1 / e - offset / g0` 
`-(xe² + ye²)/2 = ln(1 / e - offset / g0)` 
`xe² + ye² = -2 * ln(1 / e - offset / g0)`

That's it! We got our circle expression where the radius `r` is `-2*ln(1 / e - offset / g0)`! Note that `ln` in the expression is basically the natural logarithm.

Now we could try to find the 4x4 matrix coefficients, or actually try to directly solve the full expression which is finally not so difficult.

`offset + g0 * exp(-((x-x0)²/(2*sigma_x²) + (y-y0)²/(2*sigma_y²))) = g0 / e` 
`exp(-((x-x0)²/(2*sigma_x²) + (y-y0)²/(2*sigma_y²))) = 1 / e - offset / g0` 
`-((x-x0)²/(2*sigma_x²) + (y-y0)²/(2*sigma_y²)) = ln(1 / e - offset / g0)` 
`((x-x0)²/sigma_x² + (y-y0)²/sigma_y²)/2 = -ln(1 / e - offset / g0)` 
`(x-x0)²/sigma_x² + (y-y0)²/sigma_y² = -2 * ln(1 / e - offset / g0)`

That's it! We got you conic expression where `r = -2 * ln(1 / e - offset / g0)` is a constant, `a = sigma_x` and `b = sigma_y` are the unknown parameter in the above expression. It can be normalized using `a = sigma_x/sqrt(r)` and `b = sigma_y/sqrt(r)` so the right hand side is 1 fitting exactly with the above expression but this is just some math details.

You can find one point of the ellipse easily since you know the centre of the ellipse `(x0, y0)` and there is at least 1 point at the intersection of the line `y=y0` and the above conic expression. Lets find it:

`(x-x0)²/sigma_x² + (y0-y0)²/sigma_y² = -2 * ln(1 / e - offset / g0)` 
`(x-x0)²/sigma_x² = -2 * ln(1 / e - offset / g0)` 
`(x-x0)² = -2 * ln(1 / e - offset / g0) * sigma_x²` 
`x = sqrt(-2 * ln(1 / e - offset / g0) * sigma_x²) + x0`

Note there are two solutions (`-sqrt(...) + x0`) but you only need one of them. I hope I did not make any mistake in the computation (at least the details should be enough to find it easily) and the solution is not a complex number in your case. The benefit of this solution is that it is **very very fast to compute**.

**The final solution is:** 
**`(xe, ye) = (sqrt(-2*ln(1/e-offset/g0)*sigma_x²)+x0, y0)`**

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. The derivation seems to check out. I am wondering though, the final solution here is a complex number. My (xe,ye) are supposed to be real numbers. How can I obtain that?

Comment: I think you can get complex numbers if the value in the square root is negative or if the value in the log is negative too. This is not supposed to be possible unless there is no solution in this specific case or unless there is an error in the final analytic expression. Assuming the expression is valid, this is possible if `f(x, y)` cannot gives in `g0 / e`. For example if `offset/g0 >1/e` (causing a log of a negative value). I can check this if you have an example of practical parameters causing that.